# Trim whitespace from middle of string

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm using the following regex to capture a fixed width "description" field that is always 50 characters long:

```
(?.{50})
```

My problem is that the descriptions sometimes contain a *lot* of whitespace, e.g.

```
"FLUID        COMPRESSOR                          "
```

Can somebody provide a regex that:

1. Trims all whitespace off the end
2. Collapses any whitespace in between words to a **single space**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Substitute two or more spaces for one space:

```
s/  +/ /g
```

Edit: for any white space (not just spaces) you can use \s if you're using a perl-compatible regex library, and the curly brace syntax for number of occurrences, e.g.

```
s/\s\s+/ /g
```

or

```
s/\s{2,}/ /g
```

Edit #2: forgot the /g global suffix, thanks JL

Comment: Or even just s/\s+/ /g -- it occasionally maps a single space to another single space, but it hardly matters.  But the global suffix does matter, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately all proposed regexes leave one space at the end if it was there in the initial string.

Answer (score 9):

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, " +( |$)", "$1");
```

Comment: Bravo! This regex correctly processes spaces between words and at the end of string.

Comment: Same thing I was going to suggest. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl-variants:
1) s/\s+$//;
2) s/\s+/ /g;

Answer (score 2):

C#:

Only if you wanna trim all the white spaces - at the start, end and middle.

```
     string x = Regex.Replace(x, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you are asking for a regular expression? They may not be the best tool for this task.

A replacement like

```
 s/[ \t]+/ /g
```

should compress the internal whitespace (actually, it will compress leading and trailing whitespace too, but it doesn't sound like that is a problem.), and

```
s/[ \t]+$/$/
```

will take care of the trailing whitespace. [I'm using `sed`ish syntax here. You didn't say what flavor you prefer.]

---

Right off hand I don't see a way to do it in a single expression.

Comment: I'm using this inside of a larger regular expression, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162727/read-fixed-width-record-from-text-file

Answer (score 1):

Since compressing whitespace and trimming whitespace around the edges are conceptually different operations, I like doing it in two steps:

```
re.replace("s/\s+/ /g", str.strip())
```

Not the most efficient, but quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

/(^[\s\t]+|[\s\t]+([\s\t]|$))/g replace with $2 (beginning|middle/end)