# removing random whitespace

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

All,

I have some indexed text that I would like to format in a more uniform manor. For example:

```
I    live in  Virginia   and it is  raining     today
```

I would like that to print out as

```
I live in Virginia and it is raining today
```

I am writing my application in Python so if anyone knows how to do this sort of string manipulation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Adam

Comment: Regexes to trim spaces between words to just 1 in this: possible duplicate of [Trim whitespace from middle of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216870/trim-whitespace-from-middle-of-string). If you don't know Python's `re` module, this is an answer that shows it's use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216870/trim-whitespace-from-middle-of-string/1250923#1250923

Comment: `re.sub(r'[ \t]{2,}', ' ', str)`. Be careful when using `\s` instead, since that includes new lines and carriage returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions do work here, but are probably overkill. One line without any imports would take care of it:

```
sentence = 'I    live in  Virginia   and it is  raining     today'
' '.join([segment for segment in sentence.split()])
```

Comment: Why not just `' '.join(sentence.split())`?

Comment: yes, this is needlessly complicated I guess, constructing the same list from an original list, and there is a space between `' '` and `.join..`

Answer (score 9):

A very simple approach:

```
s = "I    live in  Virginia   and it is  raining     today"
words = s.split()
print ' '.join(words)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to accomplish this

```
import re
s = 'I    live in  Virginia   and it is  raining     today'
print re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)
```

Comment: As NullUserException pointed out - r'[ \t]{2,}' would be used to replace spaces or tabs. I just did a general whitespace replace in my answer.