# How to Read Process output as Model

Tags: c#

I can get the output of the process with the following codes

```
var p = new Process
{
  StartInfo =
  {
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = "cmd",
    Arguments = "list id"
   }
 };
 p.Start();
 var _Data = await p.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
 await p.WaitForExitAsync();

 File.WriteAllText("asd.txt", _Data);
```

In the output I have information like this

```
Name   Id            Version
----------------------------
WinRAR RARLab.WinRAR 6.01.0
```

The question is how can I get the 3 fields of name, id and version?

Comment: You'll have to [parse the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split). Unless you are asking for just this specific example there's no general way to do this as the output from two different processes can be very different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read fixed width record from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162727/read-fixed-width-record-from-text-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is tab delineated in this case, so you can `.Split(‘\t’)` the first and third lines of output and use the non-empty elements of the resultant arrays. There is an overload of `Split` that uses the  `StringSplitOptions` enum, which will allow you to ignore empty elements.  You want `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

However, if you used PowerShell instead of a Process, you’d get data back that would let you access the value by name (“Name”, “Version”, etc). Food for thought.